# Executing cmd command with variables in Ruby fails

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm writting Windows account report in Ruby. I have an array with usernames

```
users_local = [user1, user2, user3]
```

For every single user I want to execute a cmd command to get more information about every user

```
system "net user '#{users_local[0]}'"
```

and now I get

```
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.
```

When I execute directly
`system 'user net user1'` the command is executing correctly. Any ideas why executing command with variable fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of the single quotes should do it:

```
system "net user #{users_local[0]}"
```